# Generating a stateless pseudo-random number from four integers

Tags: algorithm, random, prng, perlin-noise

For an implementation of Perlin noise, I need to select a vector from a static list of *n* vectors for each integer coordinate in 3D space. This boils down to generating a pseudo random number in *1..n* from four signed integer values *x*, *y*, *z* and *seed*.

```
unsigned int pseudo_random_number(int x, int y, int z, int seed);
```

The algorithm should be stateless, i.e., return the same number each time it is called with the same input values.

An existing Perlin noise implementation I looked at multiplies each integer with a large prime, adds the results, does some bit manipulation on it and takes the reminder of a division by *n*. I don't want to just copy this because I don't understand a few things about it:

- How are the primes selected?
- Why is the additional bit manipulation done?
- How do I know if this is „sufficiently pseudo-random“ to generate a visually pleasing result?

I looked for explanations of how a PRNG works but I couldn't find anything about multiple input values.

Comment: I don't think you know what properties of "perlin noise" you want to retain, seeing as you've made your parameters integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have arbitrary precision pseudo-random number generation then you can just concatenate the four inputs (x,y,z,seed) and call your pseudo-random number generator function on this input to get the "next" pseudo-random number which will serve as your random number. (and then take the appropriate number of high bits if you want to have a random number between 1 and n).

The implementation you mentioned uses the fact that different large prime numbers, modulo n, produce essentially uncorrelated results (modulo n) when multiplied with input integers. Of course you need your input integers to not all have a universal common divisor with n for this to work. This is why the additional bit manipulation is done, so that if all of your input integers are divisible by k and n is divisible by k, the remainder modulo n will not automatically be divisible by k as well. At any rate, people have put a lot of thought into established pseudo-random number generators so my advice to you is that you trust that they considered all the potential issues and that their generator is "good" if there is a large crowd that uses it without complaints.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes sense. What would be an appropriate way to “concatenate” the input values?